# Python pyplot - Drawing arc diagram between barchart labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to draw a mix between a barchart and an arc diagram to display the mean Response time, with STD error barrs **and pairwise significance** of subjects (gathered during a user-evaluation) on different values of parameters.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW0Pw.png) is an example of my subjects performances aggregated by values of the "outCol" parameter (without pairwise significance information).

I've seen many examples where the pairwise significance information is displayed by drawing segments between plot's bars which are computed from significatively different sets. However, as my parameters can have a lot of values, I'd like, for readability, to draw these segments as arcs between the barchart labels as in this [hand-made example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUUlt.png).

Is it possible to do this with the matplotlib pyplot API ? If so, how ? (I didn't find by myself, however I'm far from being a pyplot expert)

If not, is there an other API that enables to such drawings ?

Thanks

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `clip_on=False`, an arc can be drawn outside the 'axes' area. To position the arc, a [blended transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations) where the x-coordinates are in 'data' format (0, 1, 2, ...) and the y-coordinates in 'axes' format (with `y=1` at the top spline and `y=0` at bottom spine). The 'height' of the arc can be made slightly proportional to its width, e.g. by setting `height = 0.1*np.sqrt(width)`.

Here is some example code. `plt.tight_layout()` fits the arcs into the figure:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
from matplotlib import transforms
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

labels = list('abcdef')
df = pd.DataFrame({lab: np.random.uniform(0, 100, 5) for lab in labels})

ax = sns.barplot(data=df)

arcs = [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), ('a', 'f')]

trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)
for arc_i, arc_j in arcs:
    i = labels.index(arc_i)
    j = labels.index(arc_j)
    patch = Arc(((i + j)/2, -0.1), j - i, 0.1*np.sqrt(abs(j - i)), theta1=180.0, theta2=360.0, transform=trans,
                clip_on=False, edgecolor='black', linewidth='1')
    ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]